# Is the coefficient of determination defined for higher dimensional dependent variables?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, metric, high-dimensional

The coefficient of determination has a clear definition for scalar dependent variables. See for instance the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

Can this definition easily be extended to variables in higher dimensional space, i.e. vectors (or even arbitrary tensors)? How would you go about it?

As an example, the `scikit-learn` implementation of the r2 score calculates separate scores for each dimension and returns an aggregation of this score: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html Is that a sensible interpretation, or should it be done another way?

Comment: A variable is a dimension, so for e.g. multivariate linear regression with multiple $y$ dependent variables (don't call these "dimensions") $R^2$ is not typically defined or used.  Instead, Wilks-Lambda, Lawley-Hotelling $U$, Pillai trace, and Roy's greatest root are often used for goodness-of-fit, not $R^2$.   If Scikit learn uses something other than these, than you'd need to read the manual or contact the authors on what they used.

Comment: @NXGLogic Not sure I get why it is always better to frame this as multivariate regression rather than talking about high dimensional variables. Is it technically wrong or is this more about using the common language of the field? I don't have a deep stats background, so sorry if this seems poorly formulated. I will check out the multivariate metrics you mention.

Comment: > If Scikit learn uses something other than these [...]

I guess it wouldn't be right to claim scikit learn "uses" multivariate $R^2$, but it does *provide* it, as a library function. Part of why I am asking is that I am working on another open source implementation of $R^2$ (https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/pull/1310), and I am trying to understand whether the `scikit-learn` approach is fine to imitate, or if it should be generalized in a different way.